# format the results of a database query

Tags: php, html, mysql

So far I have the following php which allows the user to search in a specific collumn of the database and displays all the results.

```
<?php
require("header.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['searching'])){ //check if form has been submitted
echo"<h2>Results</H2><p>";
connect('final');//connect to DB
//set the values from search form
$field = $_POST['field'];
$query = $_POST['query']; 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); // stop HTML characters
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query); //stop SQL injection

     $data = mysql_query("SELECT *
     FROM customer 
     INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.customer_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sites ON address.ID = sites.address_ID 
     WHERE customer.ID IN (SELECT customer.ID 
     FROM customer
     INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.customer_ID 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sites ON address.ID = sites.address_ID
     WHERE upper(customer.$field) LIKE'%$query%')") ;//query the DB with search field in colleumn selected//

     //$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.Customer_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN sites ON address.ID = sites.address_ID WHERE upper(customer.$field) LIKE'%$query%'") ;

    if($data === FALSE) {
    $error = 'Query error:'.mysql_error();
    echo $error;
    }
    else
    {
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($data)){// puts data from database into array, loops until no more
            echo "<br>"; 
            echo $results['First_Name']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['Surname']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['Company_Name']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['Telephone']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['Alt_Telephone']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['line_1']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['line2']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['town']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['postcode'];
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['site_name'];


            //posts results from db query
        }
    }


        $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); //checks if the querys returned any results
            if ($anymatches == 0) 
                    { 
                        echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
                    } 

    }
```

However as I am using echo to output it just displays all of the results at the very top of the page, and pushes all of my html content down below it.

How can I format it so that it appears in my html content? below the search button for example.

Comment: You've potential for SQL injections due to `$field`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is don't echo the content it will display at top because PHP process the code first then loads html hence it will echo the data at the top of page.

Solution is assign the result into an array in while loop then use that array to show it in html.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, closing tag 'p' will help? Try to add

```
echo "</p>";
```

in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Methinks you're missing some html tags in there, e.g.:

```
        echo "<div>"; 
        echo $results['First_Name']; 
        echo " "; 
        echo $results['Surname']; 
        echo ", "; 
        echo $results['Company_Name']; 
        echo "</div><address>"; 
        echo $results['Telephone']; 
        echo "<br>"; 
        echo $results['Alt_Telephone']; 
        echo "<br>"; 
        echo $results['line_1']; 
        echo "<br>"; 
        echo $results['line2']; 
        echo "<br>"; 
        echo $results['town']; 
        echo " "; 
        echo $results['postcode'];
        echo "</address><div>"; 
        echo $results['site_name'];
        echo "</div>";
```

If you allow a slightly OT answer, your code suggests me that you're learning PHP.

If so, keep in mind that online PHP tutorials were frequently written years ago and are in an abject state of obsolescence, complete with sample code that shows the worst possible things you could do.

Assuming my assessment is correct, consider learning PHP alongside a well designed framework. Silex is relatively easy to pick up in this respect:

- http://silex.sensiolabs.org
- http://www.google.com/search?q=silex+app+example

Other frameworks that you might want to look into:

- http://symfony.com
- http://framework.zend.com
- http://www.yiiframework.com
- http://www.fuelphp.com
- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter
- http://cakephp.org (getting old)

There are many, many more.